# How can I sequre Nuxt + Express like serverMiddleware non-authentocated post requests?

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js

Sorry for My English. I am using Nuxt 2 + Express 4 like serverMiddlewre.
Online store and users can push products to cart without authentication. Every cart saving in DataBase by POST request from Frontend to Backend.
How can i sequre my non-authenticated post request?

I remember that in YII2 was SCRF-TOKEN. generated in backend and transferring to Frontend. Only with this token backend can process post requests from Frontend